# Measurabilty question

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, manifolds, lebesgue-measure, submanifold

Consider following problem:
Let $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be a rotation.
Show that a subset $M \subset S^1$ is measurable if and only $f(M)$ is measurable.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. 

1. $f \circ \gamma$ is not a translation in $\mathbb R$. 

2. $(f \circ \gamma)^{-1}(M)$ need not be (and in general, will not be) a translation of $\gamma^{-1} (M)$.

Comment: 2. Because $\gamma: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is just any embedding, so
$(f \circ \gamma)^{-1}(M)$ need not be (and in general, will not be) a translation of  $\gamma^{-1} (M)$.

Comment: One example: Let $\Omega= (0 , 1)$. Let  $\gamma_1: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$  be defined by 
$\gamma_1(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$. $\gamma_1$ is an embedding. Let $M=\gamma_1([1/4,3/4])$. Let $f$ be the $180^\circ$ rotation. Then $\gamma^{-1} (M)=[1/4,3/4]$ and $(f \circ \gamma_1)^{-1}(M)= (0,1/4]\cup [3/4,1)$. So $(f \circ \gamma_1)^{-1}(M)$  is **not** a translation of  $\gamma^{-1} (M)$.

Comment: Another example: Let $\Omega= (0 , 1)$. Let  $\gamma_2: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$  be defined by 
$\gamma_2(x) = e^{2\pi i \frac{(x^2+x)}{2}}$. We have that $\gamma_2$ is also an embedding.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us recapitulate here

> Consider the unit circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb C$ as a submanifold of $\mathbb R ^2.$
> Choose an atlas for $S^1$. Choose a partition of unity $\{p_i\}_{i \in I}$ that is subordinate to the domains of the charts of that atlas (i.e. $\operatorname{supp}(p_i) \subset V_i$ for a domain $V_i$).
> Choose an embedding $\gamma: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ with an open $\Omega \subset \mathbb R$.
> We call a **subset $M \subset S^1$ measurable** if for all $i \in I$ the function $(\chi_M \cdot p_i )\circ \gamma \cdot \sqrt{g^\gamma}: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. Here $\chi_M$ denotes the characteristic function of $M$ and $g^\gamma$ is the Gram determinant of $d \gamma$. (One can show that this definition is independent of the choices made.)

We want to prove that

> Let $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be a rotation.
> Show that a subset $M \subset S^1$ is measurable if and only $f(M)$ is measurable.

**Proof**: We can write $(\chi_M \cdot p_i )\circ \gamma \cdot \sqrt{g^\gamma} = \chi_{\gamma^{-1}(M)}\cdot (p_i \circ \gamma)\cdot \sqrt{g^\gamma}$. The Gram determinant is non-zero because $\gamma$ is an embedding. Because of that and because the product of measurable functions is measurable, $(\chi_M \cdot p_i )\circ \gamma \cdot \sqrt{g^\gamma}$ is measurable if and only if $\chi_{\gamma^{-1}(M)}\cdot (p_i \circ \gamma)$ is measurable.

So we have:

1. $M$ is measurable if and only if, for all $i \in I$,  $\chi_{\gamma^{-1}(M)}\cdot (p_i \circ \gamma)$ is measurable (which independs of the athas chosen, the $\{p_i\}_{i \in I}$ partition of unity  that is subordinate to the domains of the charts of the atlas and the embedding $\gamma: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$).

In the same way,

2. $f(M)$ is measurable if and only if, for all $i \in I$,  $\chi_{\gamma^{-1}(f(M))}\cdot (p_i \circ \gamma)$ is measurable, (which independs of the athas chosen, the $\{p_i\}_{i \in I}$ partition of unity  that is subordinate to the domains of the charts of the atlas and the embedding $\gamma: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$).

It is easy to see that $f^{-1}\circ \gamma$ is an embedding. So by item 1, we have that  $M$ is measurable if and only if, for all $i \in I$,  $\chi_{\gamma^{-1}(f(M))}\cdot (p_i \circ f^{-1}\circ \gamma)$ is measurable. But $\{p_i \circ f^{-1}\}_{i \in I}$ is a partition of unity  that is subordinate to the domains of the charts of the atlas rotated by $f$. Let, for all $i\in I$, $p_i'= p_i \circ f^{-1}$. Then, using item 2,  we have that  $M$ is measurable if and only if, for all $i \in I$,  $\chi_{\gamma^{-1}(f(M))}\cdot (p_i'\circ \gamma)$ is measurable  if and only if $f(M)$ is measurable.
So, $M$ is measurable if and only if $f(M)$ is measurable.